# How to get date of tag from Azure Devops Cli

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm using the Azure devops cli to get a list of the tags for a particular repo.  Documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos?view=azure-cli-latest.   For example

```
az repos ref list -p <project>-r <name of repo> --filter tags
```

The result looks something like this

```
[
  {
    "creator": {
      "descriptor": "aad.ODAzODM5N2YtNWE3Yi03MzBkLThlNTktMzhmMTJlOTU0MTJi",
      "directoryAlias": null,
      "displayName": "<name>",
      "id": "8038397f-5a7b-630d-8e59-38f12e95412b",
      "imageUrl": "https:<redacted>",
      "inactive": null,
      "isAadIdentity": null,
      "isContainer": null,
      "isDeletedInOrigin": null,
      "uniqueName": "<email>",
      "url": "https://<redacted>"
    },
    "isLocked": null,
    "isLockedBy": null,
    "name": "refs/tags/1.0.0-tag-name",
    "objectId": "6ed8645a6e1c6686aa9eead0e60365665d76dfb5",
    "peeledObjectId": null,
    "statuses": null,
    "url": "https://<redacted>"
  }
]
```

There does not seem to be a date available.  I get the object id and if this was local, I could do `git show <objectid>`, but there doesn't seem to be anything in the api to get the date or any other specific information, based on an object id

Just to clarify, in my case, the date of tag creation and the date of commit is typically the same so either would be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that Azure DevOps CLI doesn't support to get the specific information based on Object Id of the Repo tag.

I suggest that you can use Rest API to achieve the requirement: [Annotated Tags - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/annotated-tags/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

**Rest API:**

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/annotatedtags/{objectId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

**Result sample:**

```
{
  "name": "refs/tags/v0.1-beta2",
  "objectId": "69080710948ac8ba63e44eca2daf0b30f38c428d",
  "taggedObject": {
    "objectId": "c60be62ebf0e86b5aa01dbb98657b4b7e5905234",
    "objectType": "commit"
  },
  "taggedBy": {
    "name": "Norman Paulk",
    "email": "Fabrikamfiber16@hotmail.com",
    "date": "2017-06-22T04:28:23"
  },
  "message": "First beta release",
  "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/c34d5807-1734-4541-ad1c-d16e9ac1faca/_apis/git/repositories/ca93c3a5-87bb-4b5b-a62f-1f971d677c79/annotatedTags/69080710948ac8ba63e44eca2daf0b30f38c428d"
}
```

You can also use Rest API to list tags of the repo: [Refs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Comment: Thanks.  Was hoping I could do it with the CLI